# How do I pick all files on iOS?

Tags: ios, angular, iphone, ionic-framework, filepicker

I have an ionic application and I am using `FilePicker.pickFile` to upload a document. The problem is that I cannot access all iPhone locations (gallery, for instance). I can only choose from iCloud Drive, My iPhone and Recently Deleted. How do I solve this ?